# Apply a function only to numeric columns in nested list and return nested list in R

Tags: r

I would like to apply the scale function only to the numeric columns in my nested list and return my nested list with the same structure but with those scaled values replaced.

Here is a dummy list for my example:

```
#Create dataframes ABC and DEF, where 'left' and 'right' columns are numeric and the 'up' column contains characters
ABC <- cbind.data.frame(left = c(2, 3, 5), right = c(5, 8, 4) , up = c("ac","bb", "cc"))
ABC$up <- as.character(ABC$up)
DEF <-  cbind.data.frame(left = c(7, 2, 9), right = c(3, 6, 1) , up = c("aa","bb", "cc"))
DEF$up <- as.character(DEF$up)

#Create a list called mylist, containing two dataframes: ABC and DEF
mylist <- list(ABC = ABC, DEF = DEF)
$ABC
#  left  right  up 
#1  2     5     aa  
#2  3     8     bb
#3  5     4     cc  

$DEF
#  left  right  up 
#1  7     3     aa  
#2  2     6     bb
#3  9     1     cc
```

I would like the scaled mylist to look like this, where the scale function subtracts each column by its mean and divides each column by its standard deviation, so scale(x, center=TRUE, scale=TRUE):

```
perfect.scaled.mylist
$ABC
#   left    right    up 
#1  -0.87   -0.32    aa  
#2  -0.22    1.12    bb
#3   1.09   -0.80    cc

$DEF
#   left    right    up 
#1   0.28   -0.13    aa  
#2  -1.11    1.05    bb
#3   0.83   -0.93    cc
```

I have tried this:

```
scaled.mylist <- lapply(lapply(mylist, `[`, -c(3)), function(x) scale(x))
$ABC
#   left    right     
#1  -0.87   -0.32      
#2  -0.22    1.12    
#3   1.09   -0.80    

$DEF
#   left    right    
#1   0.28   -0.13     
#2  -1.11    1.05   
#3   0.83   -0.93
```

which scales the 'left' and 'right' columns correctly, but it completely removes the 'up' column. So, I am thinking this part uses the scale function correctly, so I can just nest it within another lapply to send this content to my overall list.

So, I tried this:

```
scaled.nested.mylist <- lapply(mylist, function(x) lapply(lapply(x, '[', c("left", "right")), scale))
```

which returns this error `Error in colMeans(x, na.rm = TRUE) : 'x' must be numeric`. So, that did not work, and that is my best hope, and I am not sure why it failed.

Finally, I tried another function max (to get the maximum of each column) thinking that perhaps the structure of my code is correct, but it's failing on the scale function:

```
max.mylist <- lapply(mylist, function(x) lapply(lapply(x, '[', c("left", "right")), max))
$ABC
#   left  right   up 
#1  NA      NA    NA  

$DEF
#   left  right   up 
#1  NA      NA    NA
```

which successfully returns all three columns, but they are empty.

I have seen similar examples on SO, but none of them return the original nested list and instead return a new list with just the transformed columns. I do need to maintain the original list structure, because downstream functions depend on this structure. I am newer to R, and I admit I am getting lost in list-land, but I would appreciate any pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do:

```r
lapply(mylist, function(x) {
  as.data.frame(lapply(x, function(y) if(is.numeric(y)) scale(y) else y),
                stringsAsFactors = FALSE)})
#> $ABC
#>         left      right up
#> 1 -0.8728716 -0.3202563 ac
#> 2 -0.2182179  1.1208971 bb
#> 3  1.0910895 -0.8006408 cc
#> 
#> $DEF
#>         left      right up
#> 1  0.2773501 -0.1324532 aa
#> 2 -1.1094004  1.0596259 bb
#> 3  0.8320503 -0.9271726 cc
```

Comment: Wow, this works to maintain the structure of mylist. Thank you! The resulting scaled list does return the 'up' column as factors now, though. Any idea how to keep 'up' as containing characters?

Comment: Your update solves the problem, thank you! Indeed, I seem to be unintentionally using an older version of R, so I will update and then I won't need the workaround. Thank you for calling that to my attention.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option with `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
mylist2 <- map(mylist, ~ .x %>%
                  mutate(across(where(is.numeric), scale)))
```

Answer (score 1):

This can also be done with base `rapply()`:

```r
rapply(mylist, classes = "numeric", f = scale, how = "replace")
#> $ABC
#>         left      right up
#> 1 -0.8728716 -0.3202563 ac
#> 2 -0.2182179  1.1208971 bb
#> 3  1.0910895 -0.8006408 cc
#> 
#> $DEF
#>         left      right up
#> 1  0.2773501 -0.1324532 aa
#> 2 -1.1094004  1.0596259 bb
#> 3  0.8320503 -0.9271726 cc
```